# VSCode: documentation on hover doesn't show complete function documentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm learning a new API by writing some sample code in Visual Studio Code but documentation on hover cuts text abruptly and I don't want to use F12 ("go to function definition") each time to see the full documentation of a method in the header file; I suspect that VSCode doesn't like the `@ref` tag for some reason.

This is what the hover looks like:
[image: hover]

This is the actual documentation in the header file of the method (MUCH longer):
[image: actual documentation in the header file]

Note: I installed an extension to show docs in the sidebar but the problem persists, so it must be something with VSCode itself I think

Comment: similar problem: my hover doesn't even result in `@brief` being formatted correctly or any backtick text being formatted correctly. i do, however, see all the documentation text (albeit smashed together in a big text block).